# Wordpress site layout completely broken in IE9

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-9

This is a real head-scratcher.

I'm working on a site that is half static, half wordpress. Some pages are dynamic and so run through wordpress, some are entirely static so sit outside of its logic. This keeps things a tiny bit more efficient (and was a client requirement).

So these pages share identical markup, at least with regards to the 'chrome', i.e. header etc.

The thing is the static pages look (near) spot-on in IE9, but the wordpress pages are completely broken.

Here's an example:

**Static page nav bar:**

[image]

**Wordpress page navbar:**

[image]

What you're looking at is the same markup and the same CSS. It's identical. The only difference is that one page is being generated by wordpress, the other is static. The physical location of the page isn't an issue either, as there are static pages at the same directory level that don't have this issue.

The site works fine in all other browsers, this issue is specific to IE9.

Having found some vague references to similar issues I tried compatibility mode. Turning on compatibility mode (i.e. making IE9 render as IE8) actually *improves* the rendering of the page. The layout isn't great because the site hasn't been built around IE8 support, but bizarrely it looks significantly better than IE9. So although this is technically an option it's not a great one, as I know the site looks fine in IE9… just only when wordpress isn't involved.

(These screenshots are from a VM running IE9 natively, this isn't an emulator issue)

**EDIT:**

The discrepancies between the two pages in their rendered markup are as follows, in case relevant:

(This is basically what Wordpress adds through its `<?php wp_head(); ?>` call.)

Before `<!DOCTYPE html>` a couple of comments:

```
<!-- Page variables -->

<!-- Header -->
```

Some OG data and a title attribute (nothing notable though, standard markup, self closing tags etc.)

Then this lot:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="XXX" href="XXX/help-and-advice/feed/" />
<style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
    display: inline !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 1em !important;
    margin: 0 .07em !important;
    vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="XXX/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="XXX/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.3.1" />
```

(I scrubbed the URL etc. from that code, but left the important bits)

Comment: Do you have any IE specific conditionals in your header?

Comment: Only a basic shiv: `<!--[if lt IE 9 ]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->` (which as you can see should only trigger on IE8)

Comment: Indeed, my initial guess would be there's a syntax error in the CSS somewhere that isn't being ignored in IE9. Are you able to share a link? It'll help to debug.

Comment: Annoyingly I'm not in a position to share the site yet - I appreciate that doesn't make it easy to debug. The thing to keep in mind is if that's the case why would it only present itself on wordpress generated pages?

Comment: Is there any instance of `flexbox` in your CSS?

Comment: There shouldn't be no!

Comment: Might be worth checking as IE9 doesn't support it, that doesn't explain the other pages working though. I can only imagine that there's some CSS somewhere in the WP theme that either isn't formed properly or is incompatible with IE9 (sorry to state obvious)

Comment: Na I appreciate it's an odd one, lots of obvious stuff to cover! "I can only imagine that there's some CSS somewhere in the WP theme" but they're literally sharing the same CSS. As in the two pages are loading the exact same file. That's what I can't understand about it.

Comment: I just added the additional bits wordpress adds to the question, in case anything jumps out. That's the only difference between the rendered pages.

Comment: Long shot, but do you have more than 4095 selectors in your CSS? I believe there's a limit to what IE9 can parse. I'll check back later if a solution still needed.

Comment: Nah there won't be that many, good thought though (and again, if there were it'd break whether wordpress were generating the page or not).